# convert week datepart number to date within week (week of...)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, week-number, datepart

I am trying to figure out how to convert a datepart for a week to the Monday of that week.

I am using this:

```
     datepart(ww, DateCompleted) as week
```

to group a set of orders in our system by week.  My goal is for this to say instead of 37, i want it to return the Monday of week 37, i.e.: 09-10-2012.  I am able to do this by defining each week per number but i would rather not spend so much time typing out each week when there is probably a better option out there, i have just been unable to find it anywhere online other than in MySQL and other programming languages (i need T-SQL please, or anything that will work on sql server 2005), and i do not know how to work with that.  Thanks for anyone that can help. Ill be checking back as often as possible to provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course i found a solution right after posting this, thanks for anyone who looked and tried to help.  Here is the solution i found:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
declare @wk int  set @wk = 1
declare @yr int  set @yr = 2007

select dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
     datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (year, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
```

found at this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/cf233caf-4ccd-4bca-add2-b5eb467f2dd4

Answer (score 3):

You can combine [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420) to get the monday of the date supplied:

```
DATEADD(day, (-1 * DATEPART(dw, datecompleted)) + 2, datecompleted)
```

Example [found here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9412/7/0)

Comment: @wondergoat77: No problem, but be warned: Using this method makes Sundays the week of the following Monday. (i.e. this past sunday [9/9/2012] is the week of 9/10/2012) So if you want your week to be Monday-Sunday, this needs modification.